# Flask-User, how to use a uuid instead of int as user id

Tags: flask, flask-login

I am using flask-security at the moment, and I am thinking of changing it to flask-user, mostly for the 'USER_REQUIRE_INVITATION' functionality, as I would prefer not to write an invitation system.

flask-user==0.6.21

The database structure seem similar, so it looks to be a drop in replacement.

The one is that flask-user uses an int for user id, whereas with flask-security I used a uuid.
This causes errors:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '29d726e2-e160-4cbc-b0d8-befeca8bdeb6'
```

This is due to uuid being cast to int ( in flask-user codebase ).

```
    def setup_login_manager(self, app):

    # Flask-Login calls this function to retrieve a User record by user ID.
    # Note: user_id is a UNICODE string returned by UserMixin.get_id().
    # See https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#how-it-works
    @self.login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user_by_id(user_unicode_id):
        user_id = int(user_unicode_id)
        #print('load_user_by_id: user_id=', user_id)
        return self.get_user_by_id(user_id)
```

I prefer using a uuid vs and int.
Is there any good way of using flask-user with uuid ?

Edit: I am using a text for a uuid

```
id = db.Column(
    'id', db.Text(), default=lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()), primary_key=True)
```

Comment: The [primary keys](http://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/limitations.html#primary-keys) part of Flask-User said it can be strings.

Comment: Thanks but that is for v1.0 which is in 'alpha'.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your User model looks like, the id should probably be something like this. A UUID can be represented as string.

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    pk = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self.pk

    @id.setter
    def id(self, value):
        self.pk = value
```